# ¿Cómo filtrar por día de semana? en MySQL

Tags: postgresql, date-format

Necesito una consulta mysql para filtrar por día de semana.

ejemplo 1:

tengo estas fecha por formato (1995-01-01), la columna a la que hago referencia se llama "release_date" de la tabla "Movies" (no se puede cambiar el formato forzadamente)

| ID | title | release_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Four Rooms (1995) | 1995-01-01 |
| 2 | Copycat (1995) | 1995-01-01 |
| 25 | Birdcage, The (1996) | 1996-03-08 |

Y quiero filtrar todas por día "Lunes" (por ejemplo SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE release_date = "x_Lunes_x")

probé con dayofweek(); DATE_FORMAT(); day; tal vez no sepa utilizarla, pero me aparece el error "SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function dayofweek(date) does not exist"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalmente las funciones de fecha devuelven el día de la semana con la siguiente secuencia: 1=Domingo, 2=Lunes, ..., 7=Sábado

**En PostgreSQL**

Aunque hay diferentes métodos, puedes utilizar la función extract:

```
select * 
fROM Movies 
WHERE extract(isodow from release_date) = 2;
```

Se sobreentiende que el campo release_date es del tipo `timestamp` o `date`.

**En MySQL**

La función `DAYOFWEEK()` si [que existe](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek).

Por lo que tu consulta para obtener los registros cuya fecha caiga en lunes debe ser:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Movies 
WHERE DAYOFWEEK(release_date) = 2
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder Roger, me aparece el siguiente error "SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function dayofweek(date) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 32"

Comment: ¿Qué versión de MySQL utilizas?

Comment: PostgreSQL 12.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit

Comment: He editado la respuesta con la opción de PostgreSQL

Comment: Funciona perfecto estimado, muchas gracias por la aclaración